# refresh after .showDialog and show items in list - c# .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Currently in my program a user opens form 1 to create a new instance of a class and it is then saved to a list. After form 1 closes I would like the main form to reload and show the updated list on the screen. I am having trouble figuring out how to refresh the main navigation and how I would get the list to show on the form.

MainNaviagation

```
    public partial class MainNavigation : Form
    {
        private Model m_modelObj;
        public MainNavigation(Model modelObj)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            m_modelObj = modelObj;

            m_modelObj.ChocolateAdded += m_modelObj_ChocolateAdded;
        }

        void m_modelObj_ChocolateAdded(Chocolate newChocolate)
        {

            //whole list of chocolates
            List<Chocolate> chocolateList = m_modelObj.ChocolateList;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string candy = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            Form1 aForm1 = new Form1(textBox1.Text, candy, m_modelObj);
            aForm1.ShowDialog();

        }


    }
```

Model Class:

```
{
    public delegate void ChocolateAddedEventHander(Chocolate newChocolate);
    public class Model
    {
        public event ChocolateAddedEventHander ChocolateAdded;


        public List<Chocolate> ChocolateList = new List<Chocolate>();
        public void AddChocolateInList(Chocolate chocolate)
        {
            ChocolateList.Add(chocolate);

            if (ChocolateAdded != null)
                ChocolateAdded(chocolate);
        }
    }
```

form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Model m_model;
        public Form1(string name, string candy, Model modelObj)
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            m_model = modelObj;

            string str = name + " selected : ";
            label1.Text = str;

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Chocolate newChocolate = new Chocolate(comboBoxChocolateSelection.SelectedItem.ToString(), 12.5, true, 2);
            m_model.AddChocolateInList(newChocolate);

            this.Close();

        }

    }
```

chocolates

```
public class Chocolate
    {
        #region Fields
        public string flavor;
        public double cost;
        public bool giftWrap;
        public int quantity;

        #endregion End of Fields

        #region Constructors 
        public Chocolate(string flavor, double cost, bool giftWrap, int quantity)
        {
            this.flavor = flavor;
            this.cost = cost;
            this.giftWrap = giftWrap;
            this.quantity = quantity;
        }
        #endregion End of Constructors


    }
```

Comment: If you close the form, you will lose all the data in the list as it belongs to the form object.

Comment: Well, when you receive the call to your event handler in the MainNavigation your model object has the new item already in its internal list so you just need to add the Chocolate object passed through the event handler to your ListBox or whatever you use to display the internal list of the model

Comment: By the way, can you add the code that initialize your listbox or other control used to display the list on the MainNavigation form?